# how to change the value of a column of a sequence?

Tags: postgresql

Which is the best way to

1)rename this sequence from episode_id_seq to sequence_id_seq

2)rename the value of sequence_name to sequence_id_seq from episode_id_seq

3)rename the owned value from episode.id to sequence.id

```
test777=# \d episode_id_seq
   Sequence "public.episode_id_seq"
Column     |  Type   |        Value
---------------+---------+---------------------
sequence_name | name    | episode_id_seq
last_value    | bigint  | 1
start_value   | bigint  | 1
increment_by  | bigint  | 1
max_value     | bigint  | 9223372036854775807
min_value     | bigint  | 1
cache_value   | bigint  | 1
log_cnt       | bigint  | 32
is_cycled     | boolean | f
is_called     | boolean | t
Owned by: public.episode.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ALTER SEQUENCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html)

1. ALTER SEQUENCE episode_id_seq RENAME TO sequence_id_seq;
2. As above.
3. ALTER SEQUENCE episode_id_seq OWNED BY sequence.id;

Comment: 1) and 3) worked. How do i change the value of the column sequence_name to scene_id_seq? I am getting this error



     test777=# alter sequence scene_id_seq set sequence_name scene_id_seq;
     ERROR:  syntax error at or near "sequence_name"
     LINE 1: alter sequence scene_id_seq set sequence_name scene_id_seq;